# I am getting Error in python array while reading EDF file. why?

Tags: python, arrays, european-data-format

I am getting the following traceback from the code below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shafi/anaconda3/envs/NEW37/Lib/encodings/EDFreadingchina.py", line 36, in <module>
    sigbufs=upload_brain_wave_file()
  File "C:/Users/shafi/anaconda3/envs/NEW37/Lib/encodings/EDFreadingchina.py", line 23, in upload_brain_wave_file
    sigbufs[i,:]=f.readSignal(i)
IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 1-dimensional, but 2 were indexed
```

Here is the code:

```
import pyedflib
import numpy as np
import os

def upload_brain_wave_file():
    brain_wave_list=[]
    #brain_wave= os.path.join(os.getcwd(),f"datasets/brain_wave")
    brain_wave="C:\\Users\\shafi\\PycharmProjects\\pyHrv\\SN001.edf"

    f= pyedflib.EdfReader(brain_wave)
    n=f.signals_in_file
    print("signal numbers:",n)
    signal_lebels = f.getSignalLabels()
    print("Labels:", signal_lebels,len(signal_lebels),sep="\n==========\n")
    sample_signal=f.getSampleFrequency(chn=n)
    # print('sample_signal',sample_signal.shape)
    # signal_headers=f.getSignalHeaders() #আগে এটা ছিল
    signal_headers=f.getSignalHeader(7)
    print("Header:",signal_headers,len(signal_headers),sep="\n===\n")
    sigbufs=np.zeros((f.getNSamples()[0]))
    timestart=f.getFileDuration()
    print('timestart',timestart)
    for i in np.arange(n):
        sigbufs[i,:]=f.readSignal(i)
        print('ooo',sigbufs)
        label= f.getLabel(i)
        sample_rate=f.getSampleFrequency(i)
        # print("sample_rate",sample_rate)
        d=list(enumerate(sigbufs[0,0:sample_rate]))
        print('da',d)
        # print({label:sigbufs[0,0:10]})
        # return  {label:sigbufs[0,0:256]}
    # print(sigbufs.shape)

    #return sigbufgs

sigbufs=upload_brain_wave_file()
print(sigbufs)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(*np.array(list(enumerate(sigbufs[0,0:256]))).T, linestyle='-', linewidth=1,color='dodgerblue')
plt.show()
```